# Set-QADUser fails because it returns a group instead of a user

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a script which updates various AD properties from a CSV.

It works fine, except for a couple of users. Their login names are short, DA and RS respectively, and I get the following error:

```
Set-QADUser : Target object is of invalid type: 'group'. 'user' expected.
```

The code on the offending line is:

```
Set-QADUser DA -Title "Manager"
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - used the DN instead of the SAM Account Name